# unable to create join table with two foreign keys sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I get the following error after trying to create a join table with two foreign keys.

`Error: near "user_id": syntax error`

Here is my code for creating the join table:

```html
sqlite> CREATE TABLE reviews (
   ...> id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   ...> stars INT,
   ...> comment TEXT,
   ...> business_id INT,
   ...> FOREIGN KEY (business_id) REFERENCES businesses(id),
   ...> user_id INT,
   ...> FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
   ...> );
```

Here are the other tables:

```html
CREATE TABLE users (
   ...> id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   ...> first_name TEXT,
   ...> last_name TEXT
   ...> );
   
   CREATE TABLE businesses(
   ...> id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   ...> name VARCHAR(250)
   ...> );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constraints should go after all the column definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE reviews (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    stars INT,
    comment TEXT,
    business_id INT,
    user_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (business_id) REFERENCES businesses(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/a4f74) is a SQL Fiddle.